# Statistically compare two algorithm outputs

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data

I want to test the efficiency of two different algorithms.

I have two random samples from the same population. On one sample, I run Algorithm X; on another sample, I run Algorithm Y. There are 30 records in each. The variable type is continuous.

Which statistics test I can do to find out the best algorithm and what parameters I should be comparing?

Kindly let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: You seem to have paired data, I added the relevant tag. Can you show us a plot of the differences? Running times are propbably not close to a normal distributi9on, so maybe a permutation test?

Comment: Hi Kjetil
Thank you for your reply. The only difference between two algorithm is the scale of inputs. The function of algorithm takes care of the scale and gives "uniform" output.

A sample of the data is below

Algorithm X 
Input         Output
 567,000.00  3.158
 504,804.00  2.756
 492,771.00  3.001
 516,688.00  3.422
 
Algorithm Y 
Input                 Output
 6,007,310.00          3.643
 7,894,562.00  3.942
 8,456,123.00  3.188
 5,875,200.00  3.419

Comment: Maybe you can show us aplot?